# Lambda expression button.setOnAction is not working outside the Main class

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to attach a lambda expression to a button to fire a method. I want that lambda outside the Main method of class and outside a method.   I have imported javafx.event.ActionEvent not to mix up with java.awt.event.ActionEvent.  I might not be explaining the problem in an understandable way but hopefully the code will help.
Note: I have tried to use lambda expression within a method, outside a method, just to see if it works but it doesn't work outside a.

Error message is "Can't resolve symbol'setOnAction' "

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class DashboardController {

    @FXML
    private Label lblHidden;
    @FXML
    private Button btnReveal;

    @FXML
    void backToLogin(ActionEvent event) throws Exception{
        Parent myRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
        Scene loginScence = new Scene(myRoot);
        Stage myStage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        myStage.setScene(loginScence);
        myStage.setTitle("Login");
        myStage.show();

        //Lambda works though not need here - inside a method
        btnReveal.setOnAction(e->{
            lblHidden.setText("Lambda inside a method - works");
        });

    }
      //Lambda doesn't work here - -- I want it to work here
      btnReveal.setOnAction(e->{`enter code here`
        lblHidden.setText("Lambda doesn't work here");
    });

}
```

Comment: Doesn't that cause a compile error? The last btnReveal.setOnAction() won't work because it's not in a method

Comment: In Java, code like that must be in an initializer block, constructor, or method. What are you trying to accomplish by having that code outside a method?

Comment: @Slaw, thank you I should have implemented the Initializable and include the code inside the initialize method. That was dumb of me to try it outside initialize method.